# vim - should i place all .vim files when enabling a plugin in vimfiles or vim74 folder?

Tags: vim

Do all .vim files go into vimfiles or vim 74 folders when installing a plugin? on windows 7 and is this the standard for all vim plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a single `name.vim` file, that usually goes into `%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\vimfiles\plugin\` on Windows. If this doesn't exist yet, create it. You can check the actual locations from within Vim via

```
:echo &runtimepath
```

Directories under `C:\Program Files\vim\vim74` are reserved for the scripts that come with Vim. You must not put any files there; that'll just cause problems when upgrading!

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, third party plugins and colorschemes are supposed to go in this directory:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\
```

including your `vimrc` if you only use Vim 7.4:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc
```

Comment: I'll add, that the $VIM/vim74 is dedicated to vim default files. If you install anything there, I'll get lost the day you update to vim 7.5 (or 8.0). `:h 'rtp'` will give you hints about how the directories are used.